# Unexpected token '<' for Nested URL Paths in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-s3, react-router, clojurescript, aws-amplify, re-frame

I have a React web application built with AWS Amplify hosted in an S3 bucket.

I was always able to do navigation within the app (clicking on router links for example), but if I attempted to directly navigate to or refresh any page in the browser other than root, the page would be completely blank.

I added the following Rewrite rule and that solved the issue for routes a single / away from root. For example, I can now refresh the page or navigate directly to https://example.com/users

[image]

However, the issue persists when the URL route is nested beyond that.

For example, https://example.com/users/profile will still be a blank page if I route directly to it by typing the address in the URL bar or if I refresh the page while on it.

When I open the JS console to check for erros (Chrome browser) I see the following error:

```
app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? I can't seem to find a solution that works. I've read that adding `homepage: "/"` to package.json or changing the start_url in the manifest.json file from "." to "/" should resolve this, but I've tried both and it did not work.

Any tips or guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: I don't know a single thing about AWS Amplify but the `Unexpected token '<'` error likely means that instead of serving `app.js` with the actual JavaScript it is receiving some HTML. You can verify that by opening the `app.js` URL directly in the Browser.

Comment: @ThomasHeller how would I resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem appears to have been the way I was importing app.js in my html file.

I was importing it as follows: `<script src="js/app.js"/>`

I changed it to: `<script src="/js/app.js"/>`

and that did the trick. Now my pages refresh normally.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue - nested routes breaking on refresh or direct navigation. But my app was a Create React App.

Solved it by removing a line in my `package.json` which contained `"homepage": "."`. As a result, my app's scripts changed from `src="./static/js/bundle.js"` to `src="/static/js/bundle.js"`, and everything works now.